# git apply fails when adding a binary file with `-p2` flag?

Tags: git, patch

I've create a patch file which includes a binary file using:

```
$ git format-patch --stdout myref^ > patch.diff
```

But when I try to apply it with:

```
$ git apply -p2 patch.diff
```

I get the error: `fatal: git diff header lacks filename information when removing 2 leading pathname components (line 2868)`.

Line 2868 is `new file mode 100755`, and here is the diff with some context:

```
 2866      … end of previous hunk …
 2867 diff --git a/some/path/foo.png b/some/path/foo.png
 2868 new file mode 100755
 2869 index 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000..3c137aa6ba759f2267f75203d6d248be89043beb
 2870 GIT binary patch
 2871 literal 363713
 2872 zcmV(@K-RyBP)xh;3K|Lk000e1NJLTq00UqE008_50ssI2p1e?20000PbVXQnQ*UN;
```

What's going on? Is there any way I could apply this patch without manually fixing it up?

Notes:

- The error is obviously incorrect, as removing 2 leading path components from `a/some/path/foo.png` yields `path/foo.png`, which is valid.
- I eventually "fixed" this problem by manually removing the unwanted leading path components: `%s:\([ab]\)/some:\1:g`.
- I am certain that there are no hunks which *would* yield an invalid path with the first two path components removed.

This is with git version 1.7.3.1 on a Mac, and the patch was created on Linux.

Here is a patch file which demonstrates the issue:

```
From 174c35d2f4a8794608eccd31b9f7d361b5ee58c3 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: David Wolever <david@wolever.net>
Date: Mon, 7 Jan 2013 13:31:42 -0500
Subject: [PATCH] Added binary file

---
 subdir/binfile.tgz |  Bin 0 -> 153 bytes
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 subdir/binfile.tgz

diff --git a/subdir/binfile.tgz b/subdir/binfile.tgz
new file mode 100644
index 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000..f71f21d3357260edea2fb7b4641a35031c759393
GIT binary patch
literal 153
zcmb2|=3wX(c^$yO{Pz4_zC#KUZV%7Jv4$u7$b3+>V$q5W-=o(~i~CwxWXP!KJ&(NC
zT4Pyq@_6dLr^}Qym*z%)j7Wc5++E4Nw&l{L%+*`M!aP!Y3VSD*E>64d{mt2P<}Z<B
z277AFj|yCBw_ZPA$o~DBBju}0Z{$4AtM@n_Tp#zxnu7rue3)vzamprF1`P%V0B|lt
AD*ylh

literal 0
HcmV?d00001

-- 
1.7.3.1
```

(taken from http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Using-git-am-p-2-with-binary-patches-td5122345.html)